# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar valores en columna de tabla MySql usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una página HTML donde muestro una tabla extraída desde phpMyAdmin, la extracción lo hago con PHP, de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php 
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ejemplo";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }

    $salida = "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE id NOT LIKE '' ORDER By nom LIMIT 25";
    
    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE Id LIKE '%$q%' OR nom LIKE '%$q%' OR canal LIKE '%$q%' OR numero LIKE '$q' ";
    }
$resultado = $conn->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

        $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr id='titulo'>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Nombre</td>
                            <td>Canal</td>
                            <td>Numero</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['nom']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['canal']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['numero']."</td>
                    </tr>";
        }

        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
        
    }else{
        $salida.="No hay datos :(";
    }

    echo $salida;
    $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Y luego muestro por html, con la siguiente forma tomada desde una función por Javascript:

```
$(mostrar_datos());

function mostrar_datos(consulta){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'App/buscar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {consulta: consulta},
    })
    .done(function(respuesta){
        $("#datos").html(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
    })
}

$(document).write('#caja_busqueda', function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
});
```

Según eso, quisiera ahora, tomar los valores de la columna numero, y poder actualizarlos desde php, para que varien cada 3 segundos.
¿Cómo puedo seleccionar datos desde una columna especifica?
¿Cómo puedo modificarlos desde una funcion PHP?

[image: Tabla con ID y Datos]

De la siguiente tabla, se quiere tomar la columna "Datos", y hacer que los datos varien o se actualicen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando estás creando la tabla puedes ir actualizando el resultado de cada fila usando la función [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.random-int.php):

```
    // Define valores mínimo y máximo
    $min = -10;
    $max = 10;
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Genera el nuevo valor al azar
        $valor = random_int($min, $max);
        // Ejecuta la consulta para actualizar
        $conn->query("UPDATE rating SET numero = $valor WHERE id = {$fila['id']}");
        $salida.="<tr>
                    <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nom']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['canal']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['numero']."</td>
                </tr>";
    }
```

En este caso, la actualización se realiza cada que vez que accedes a la página, no es posible especificar el periodo en que deseas que se haga, a menos que tengas una tarea programada.

Por ahora, la mejor opción es consultar cada determinado tiempo con AJAX y `setTimeout()` en una función recursiva o `setInterval()` para actualizar el contenido según el tiempo deseado.

### Muy importante

Lo ideal sería crear un [evento en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) para optimizar el consumo de recursos. Lamentablemente, desconozco cómo lograrlo, específicamente obtener un valor negativo o positivo con el uso de [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Ejemplo para crear evento https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540561/how-to-schedule-a-mysql-event-on-every-xx50-seconds (en inglés).

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisare el enlace, si logro hacerlo de una forma sin utilizar eventos en MySQL, lo agrego aquí. Saludos

Comment: Lo logre usando <setInterval> Gracias